# Querying a shading node Maya Python

Tags: python, maya

I am currently having a problem where i want to query the 'inputX' of a multiplyDivide Node in maya and put the queried number into the 'inputX' of another multiplyDivide node.

The script currently makes an stretchy IK set up for an arm. Using a distanceBetween the shoulder and the wrist (at a certain point, which is what i want to query) the bones would then stretch. So obviously, I don't want to connect the two together.

```
def stretchyIK(firstJointStore, lastJointStore, side, limb):

    GlobalMoveRig = cmds.rename ('GlobalMove_Grp_01')
    locFirstJoint = cmds.spaceLocator (n='Loc_' + firstJointStore + '_0#')
    locLastJoint = cmds.spaceLocator (n='Loc_' + lastJointStore + '_0#')
    pointLoc1 = cmds.pointConstraint (side + '_Fk_' + firstJointStore + suffix, locFirstJoint)
    pointLoc2 = cmds.pointConstraint (side + '_Fk_' + lastJointStore  + suffix, locLastJoint)
    cmds.delete (pointLoc1, pointLoc2)
    cmds.pointConstraint (side + '_FK_' + firstJointStore + suffix, locFirstJoint)
    cmds.pointConstraint (ikCtr, locLastJoint)
    cmds.parent (locFirstJoint, locLastJoint, 'Do_Not_Touch')
    #Creating Nodes for Stretchy IK
    IkStretch_DisNode = cmds.shadingNode ('distanceBetween', asUtility=True, n='DistBet_IkStretch_' + side + limb + '_#')
    cmds.connectAttr (locFirstJoint[0] + '.translate', IkStretch_DisNode + '.point1')
    cmds.connectAttr (locLastJoint[0] + '.translate', IkStretch_DisNode + '.point2')
    IkStretch_DivNode = cmds.shadingNode ('multiplyDivide', asUtility=True, n='Div_IkStretch_' + side + limb + '_#')
    cmds.setAttr (IkStretch_DivNode + '.operation', 2)
    input = cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_DisNode + '.distance', IkStretch_DivNode + '.input1.input1X')   ########HELP NEEDED HERE
    cmds.setAttr (ikCtr + '.translateX', 2)
    IkStretch_MultNode = cmds.shadingNode ('multiplyDivide', asUtility=True, n='Mult_IkStretch_' + side + limb + '_#')
    cmds.setAttr (IkStretch_MultNode + '.input1X', IkStretch_DivNode + '.input1.input1X')#WAIT FOR PAUL
    cmds.connectAttr (GlobalMoveRig + '.scaleY', IkStretch_MultNode + '.input2X')
    cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_MultNode + '.outputX', IkStretch_DivNode + '.input2X')
    IkStretch_Cond_Equ = cmds.shadingNode ('condition',  asUtility=True, n='Cond_Equ_IkStretch_' + side + limb + '_#')
    IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu = cmds.shadingNode ('condition',  asUtility=True, n='Cond_GrtEqu_IkStretch_' + side + limb + '_#')
    cmds.setAttr (IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu + '.operation', 3)
    cmds.connectAttr (ikCtr + '.Enable', IkStretch_Cond_Equ + '.firstTerm')
    cmds.setAttr (IkStretch_Cond_Equ + '.secondTerm', 1)
    cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_DisNode + '.distance', IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu + '.firstTerm')
    cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_MultNode + '.outputX', IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu + '.secondTerm')
    cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_DivNode + '.outputX', IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu + '.colorIfTrueR')
    cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu + '.outColorR', IkStretch_Cond_Equ + '.colorIfTrueR')
    cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu + '.outColorR', side + '_Ik_' + secondJointStore + suffix + '.scaleX')
    cmds.connectAttr (IkStretch_Cond_GrtEqu + '.outColorR', side + '_Ik_' + firstJointStore + suffix + '.scaleX')
```

Comment: What's your error message? If you ain't got one, what is the resulting behaviour of this script and what did you expect? My knowledge in rigging is really limited so I'll try to help you as much as I can.

Comment: The error is...
"Error reading data element number 1: Div_IkStretch_lArm_1.input1.input1X"
Thank you getting back to me quickly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your error makes perfect sense... The attribute you're looking for is actually just `'.input1X'` rather than `'.input1.input1X'`.

I know, that isn't very clear, but you'll know in the future. An easy way of figuring out stuff like this, by the way, is manually connecting stuff in Maya and seeing the MEL output in the script editor. You'll get the real deal every time, and translating that stuff to Python afterwards is quick.

**So**:

```
cmds.connectAttr(IkStretch_DisNode + '.distance', IkStretch_DivNode + '.input1X')
```

By the way, I'm not sure why you were assigning the result to `input`. I admit I'm not sure what that would return, but I don't see how it could be any useful!

**Additionally**: To answer your direct question, you can use `getattr` to query the value.

```
cmds.setAttr(
    IkStretch_MultNode + '.input1X', 
    cmds.getattr(IkStretch_DivNode + '.input1X')
)
```

Comment: Ahh, that makes complete sense, thank you. I have been staring it this for too long so didn't see this but now i feel stupid! Thank you very much!

Comment: @robek No worries. I remember I even had the same issue the first time around too, so I can relate ;) (If this answered your question, please don't forget to mark the answer with the green tick!)

Comment: Sorry, this was my first time asking a question so i didn't realise! Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the variable being assigned to be set as the new attribute value was not being evaluated properly. `setAttr` interpreted the variable value as text, even though the value was input as a float value.

So, I simply assigned the variable and set it to float the variable within the command. In my case, I did the following:

```
cmds.setAttr(Node + '.input1X', float(variable))
```